# How to make buildbot nine host an html resource?

Tags: buildbot

I used to use buildbot eight before, where i was able to access my html artifacts generated by tests by just using URL:

`<server>:<port>/path_to_resource`,

where path to resource was in `<preifx>/master/public_html`.

I can't access it in buildbot 0.9.10 as I get `resource not found`.

I wonder if there is an option what would allow me to access my html files from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

This feature was [removed in 0.9.0](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/installation/nine-upgrade.html).

[An issue](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/issues/3000) asks for the implementation of a plugin implementing this feature. It is still open currently with no assignee.

I have not found any other solution. I would be very interested if a solution was found.